# SAS - MD5 entire table

Tags: sas

I'm calculating a hash (md5) row by row of an entire table, 1 hash for each row.
The table is selected by the user with a prompt (&sel_lib for the selected lib and &sel_tab for the table).

1st i get my columns from sas.help.vcolumn and concatenated all to a attribute called lista:

```
data contents;
    do until (last.memname);
        set sashelp.vcolumn;
        where upcase(libname)="&sel_livraria"
        and upcase(memname)="&sel_tabela";
        by libname memname varnum;
        length lista $&max_len ; /* sum(len col) + number of col */
        lista=catx(',',lista,name);
    end;
    keep libname memname varnum lista;
run;
```

2nd i write that value in another table, because i need it for other operations not related with this issue:

```
proc sql;
    update md5_table
    set nom_colunas=(
        select lista
        from contents)
    where libname="&sel_lib"
    and memname="&sel_tab";
quit;
```

3rd Then i pass that concatenated columns to macro var `scolunas`

```
proc sql;
    select columns
    into :scolunas
    from md5_table
    where libname="&sel_lib"
    and memname="&sel_tab";
quit;
```

Then i use it to run my hash in my data step

```
data want;
    livraria="&sel_lib";
    tabela="&sel_tab";
    length check $32.;
    format check $hex32.
    set &sel_livraria..&sel_tabela.;
    check = md5(cats(&scolunas));
    hash = put(check,$hex32.);
    keep livraria tabela hash;
    put hash;
    put _all_;
run;
```

My problem is that i need to compare the output with the output of a same table in another server (plataform migration), so i need a reference to compare both.

I prefer to do that by adding a **row number of the source table** (&sel_lib &sel_tab) to my data set. Any way to do that?
A more complex one would be adding the concatenate PK values to it.

Tks in advance.

Comment: With macro you don't need to `catx` the `SET` name.  Macro is literally source code replacement when symbols are resolved, so do `SET &sel_lib..&sel_tab.;` (double dots are correct.  One dot to end the macro variable resolution, and the second literally the dot separator)

Comment: Post some actual data that gives you these peculiar check results.  You are selecting into `scolunas` and resolving `&scolumns`

Comment: Made the sugestions you gave me in my post, tks Richard.

Comment: You are mixing scope in the final data step.  check is a data step variable, so use `PUT check;` instead of `%PUT check;`.  Also `%PUT _ALL_` will log all macro variable values, and  you might want `PUT _ALL_;` that logs all variables in the data step PDV.  Can you add to the question the actual data for one row that produces a wonky MD5 result?  If you think there is too much info/sensitive, can you find a reduced row or sample data that also produces wonky MD% result?

Comment: Yeah, you right iam losing it :) Tks Richard.

Comment: Updated post again with results

Comment: You might save a lot of future headaches by first researching PROC MIGRATE.  Good landing page https://support.sas.com/rnd/migration/procmigrate/validtools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STRIP` will remove leading and trailing spaces of only **one** expression (i.e. variable) and thus accepts only a single argument.

You want your comma separated variable list concatenated as input to MD5.
`CATS()` will concatenate variables and implicitly strip.

```
...
    check = md5(cats(&scolumnlist));
...
```

If you think that data values may in some edge cases cause a concatenation that is the same in different contexts use the `CATX(<sep>,....)` to explicitly separate the fields when concatenated.

Example:

```
A   B    C   CATS()   CATX('|',)
--  ---  --  ------   ----------
PP  QQ   RR  PPQQRR   PP|QQ|RR
P   PQQ  RR  PPQQRR   P|PQQ|RR
```

Comment: Tks Richard, had to use CATS and not STRIP. But why  using <separated by ','> since my column already presents itself like col1,col2...coln?

Comment: I was working on the presumption you were working with a metadata (or control) table that had one row per column.  Since your control data already contains a comma separated list of columns for each table, I will remove the SQL in my answer.

Comment: Tks Richard, i updated my post with your remark but still not getting the expected results with my MD5